# can i give a URL to client to download files from my cpanel

Tags: wordpress, file, url, cpanel, host

i have a digital agency (wordpress), and i dont know if is posible to delivery the project from my website EX(mywebsite com/client.pdf), or other solution!
thanks

i try to upload file to File manager in my cpanel the URL file work just for me, and the other required to connect to cpanel

Answer (score 0):

upload the file to the directory within your ftp server that you want the user to be provided the link to.

for instance if you want the url to be mywebsite.com/client.pdf

go to that domains root directory in your ftp server. Drop in the file you want them to have access to and send them the link.

If you want to make it even more secure you could add a htaccess rule to integrate a password for the url ensuring its a for your eyes only situation.

Hope this helps